# Retrieve a line structure from the multi-layered ObjectNode

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, gson

I have an `ObjectNode` as input parameter, and I don't know exact structure of this node. I mean that it can have any amount of layers inside, from very simple array of `NameValuePair<String,String>` to complex structure like `HashMap<String,Object>`. How can I parse it to simple flat structure like an array of `NameValuePair<String,String>`?
I did it before for the `ObjectNodes` with the known structure, but now I have no idea.

I appreciate any help and any ideas.

Adding details:
for example, if I know, that inside the ObjectNode I will always find just `HashMap<String,String>`, and that's all, I can just do:

```
ObjectNode parametersNode = (ObjectNode) request.get("parameters");
        Iterator fieldNames = parametersNode.getFieldNames();
        HashMap<String,String> oldParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

        while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
            String name = (String) fieldNames.next();
            oldParams.put(name, parametersNode.get(name).asText());
        }
```

But what if the structure of this ObjectNode is kind of a black box? I don't know is there a Map, or an Array, or a bunch of Maps inside a Map. It can be from different sources, and I don't know what structure I will get in any moment.
it can be:

```
{
"name":"value",
"name1":"value1"
}
```

or

```
{
"name":"value",
"arg1": [
         "name1":"value1",
         "name1":"value1"
        ]
}
```

or

```
{
"name":"value",
"arg1": [
         {"name1":"value1"},
         {"name1":"value1"}
        ]
}
```

or any more complex structure.
And I have no information beforehand, what I get.
How can I convert such a black box ObjectNode to the flat array of name-value pairs? Is there any universal algorithm?

At the end I should get simple structure like that regardless complexity of the initial structure:

```
{
  "name":"value",
  "name1":"value1",
  "name2":"value2"
}
```

Comment: Please add some more detail, some code too

Comment: @Coffee I edited my message, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Could you show desired output for all examples you added?

Comment: @MichałZiober I edited the first message adding the JSON I need. Is that enough for better understanding? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it looks better now. Thanks. What if two objects have the same property "name". What we should see in result object?

Comment: @MichałZiober Each of them should be renamed: 1,2,3...N should be appended to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got no answers, I did it myself. For those who will face the same problem I post it here.
It is without any recursion and I used HashMap where I shouldn't, but it's as a proof of concept and intended to be refactored.
Please note, that it was tested as a webservice on Switchyard via Postman, so no main method.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convertToFlatFormat(
            JsonNode request) {
        Stack<Pair> stack = new Stack<Pair>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parametersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        stack.push(new Pair("", request));
        HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Pair higherNodePair = stack.pop();
            String nodeName = higherNodePair.name;
            JsonNode higherNode = (JsonNode) higherNodePair.object;
            String newNamePrefix = "";
            if (higherNode.isArray()) {
                ArrayNode higherArrayNode = (ArrayNode) higherNode;
                for (int i = 0; i < higherNode.size(); i++) {
                    JsonNode node = higherArrayNode.get(i);
                    String key = new Integer(i).toString();
                    if (node.isObject()) {
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            stack.push(new Pair(newNamePrefix, node));
                        } else {
                            stack.push(new Pair(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix
                                    , node));
                        }
                    } else if (node.isArray()) {
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            stack.push(new Pair(newNamePrefix, node));
                        } else {
                            stack.push(new Pair(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix
                                    , node));
                        }
                    } else if (node.isValueNode()) {
                        ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) node;
                        String value = valueNode.getTextValue();
                        HashMap<String, String> pair = null;
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            pair = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            pair.put(newNamePrefix + key, value);
                        } else {
                            pair = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            pair.put(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix + key,
                                    value);
                        }
                        parametersList.add(pair);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Iterator<String> iterate = higherNode.getFieldNames();
                while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterate.next();
                    JsonNode node = higherNode.get(key);
                    if (node.isObject()) {
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            stack.push(new Pair(newNamePrefix + key, node));
                        } else {
                            stack.push(new Pair(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix
                                    + key, node));
                        }
                    } else if (node.isArray()) {
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            stack.push(new Pair(newNamePrefix + key, node));
                        } else {
                            stack.push(new Pair(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix
                                    + key, node));
                        }
                    } else if (node.isValueNode()) {
                        ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) node;
                        String value = valueNode.getTextValue();
                        HashMap<String, String> pair = null;
                        if (nodeName.equals("")) {
                            pair = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            pair.put(newNamePrefix + key, value);
                        } else {
                            pair = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            pair.put(nodeName + "_" + newNamePrefix + key,
                                    value);
                        }
                        parametersList.add(pair);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return parametersList;
    }

    private class Pair {
        public String name;
        public Object object;

        public Pair(String name, Object object) {
            this.name = name;
            this.object = object;
        }
    }
```

The input is:

```
{
 "name1":"value1",
 "name2":"value2",
  "name3":[
         {
          "ComponentId":"qwer",
          "InstanceId":"amba"
         },
         {
          "ComponentId":"qwer",
          "InstanceId":"coramba"
         },
         {
          "ComponentId":"dsa",
          "InstanceId":"badar"
         },
         {
          "ComponentId":"dsa",
          "InstanceId":"fdarr"
         },
         {
          "ComponentId":"dsa",
          "InstanceId":"sdddd"
         }
         ]
}
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "name1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "name2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_1_ComponentId": "dsa"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_1_InstanceId": "sdddd"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_2_ComponentId": "dsa"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_2_InstanceId": "fdarr"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_3_ComponentId": "dsa"
    },
    {
        "name3__dsa_3_InstanceId": "badar"
    },
    {
        "name3__qwer_1_ComponentId": "qwer"
    },
    {
        "name3__qwer_1_InstanceId": "coramba"
    },
    {
        "name3__qwer_2_ComponentId": "qwer"
    },
    {
        "name3__qwer_2_InstanceId": "amba"
    }
]
```